# How to add 'Open in Vim' context menu entry to edit text files in Windows from WSL Vim

Tags: windows, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, regedit

I'd like to add a Windows right-click menu entry to quickly open text files in WSL Vim, without manually opening up a terminal.
Thanks [@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl).

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a registry key at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` named `Open in Vim`, and a subkey for it as `command`:

   `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open in Vim`

   `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open in Vim\command`
2. Edit the string value of the `command\(Default)` as `bash.exe -c "wslpath '%1' | xargs nvim"` (alternatively, you can substitute nvim with vim).
3. Download a [Vim logo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/Vimlogo.svg/1022px-Vimlogo.svg.png) which you can [convert](https://www.icoconverter.com/) online to an `.ico` extension. Create an `Icon` string value under the `Open in Vim` key, and edit its value with the path of the `.ico` image.

You can see the resulting entry below. Clicking on it would open up a WSL terminal with the selected textfile opened in Vim. Upon exitting Vim, the terminal closes, too.
[image]

Comment: This adds a context menu for all filetypes.
Is there a way to add a context menu only for textfiles?

Comment: [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5751969/joe) in that case you wanna go create this key structure and do the above described. For me the the \.txt key was completely empty, so I had to create the shell key, too.
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt\shell\Open in Vim\command`

Answer (score 0):

Add an item to the context menu to open a file in `WSL VIM` with `PowerShell`:

```sh
New-Item -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VIM\command' -Force | Out-Null;
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`*\shell\VIM' -Name '(default)' -Value 'Open in VIM' -Force | Out-Null;
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`*\shell\VIM' -Name 'Icon' -Value 'C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe,0' -Force | Out-Null;
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`*\shell\VIM\command' -Name '(default)' -Value "wsl vim -p `"`$(wslpath '%1')`"" -Force | Out-Null;
```

Or use a registry file as an alternative.

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VIM\command]
@="wsl sudo vim -p \"$(wslpath '%1')\""
```